# How to diagnose AWS port 25 egress block

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtp

I'm having trouble diagnosing what appears to be a complete blockage of outbound port 25 connections on AWS EC2.

I'm aware of the port throttling, but I don't think that's the issue. I don't think it's the issue because

1. I've been running this mail server for at least 7 years
2. Although I can't recall for sure, I'm fairly certain that I filled out the form to remove sending limitations ~ 7 years ago
3. The server only sends a few dozen emails per day
4. I've been running `tcpdump` on the interface for a while, and there are no more than a few attempts per hour to send outbound packets to anyone on port 25
5. I don't have any emails from AWS indicating I've exceeded a quota

(as an aside, the above said, is there a way to tell if AWS has turned on throttling, and/or what is the actual quota?)

I *can* `telnet` to port 25 on the AWS private networks (another aside, where does AWS perform the throttling?):

```
$ telnet 172.31.14.133 25
Trying 172.31.14.133...
Connected to 172.31.14.133.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 <mymailserver>.com ESMTP Postfix
```

I can not `telnet` to the outside world from the mail server, nor from another EC2 instance set up in this VPC for testing purposes, nor from an EC2 server set up in a different VPC. For example, the exact `telnet` that worked above does not work if I replace the private IP address with the public one (but I *can* `telnet` to the public one from the outside world).

The outbound security group rules are Ports all Protocols all 0.0.0.0/0
The network ACL for the VPC, both inbound and outbound, is Type ALL Traffic Protocol ALL Port Range ALL Destination 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW

Looking at the mail logs, it appears that no outbound SMTP traffic has succeeded since January 28th. I would think even if this were throttling, something would have worked somewhere along the way, and I'm now at a complete loss on how to move forward with diagnosing this.

***Update:*** Per suggestions below, I've gone ahead and requested removal of the limit. We'll see how that goes, but I'm still unconvinced it's the problem.

Additionally, I've turned on CloudWatch logs for the VPC. The server in question has sent 14 packets outbound to port 25 in the last 12 hours, so I really would think it would be below any throttling limit. When I look at the logs, the entries are marked as "REJECT", but still no luck on figuring out what is doing the rejecting. Is there any way to determine what "rule" is causing the reject?

Any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: You might try submitting the request to unblock, again, and mention that you thought you had it working all along, in the description. That should put you in contact with support, even without a paid support plan.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/  Let us know what they say.

Comment: This did, in fact, solve the problem. They didn't admit to having changed anything, and they didn't tell me what the actual throttle number is, but the response did have one interesting tidbit: "Email sending limitations have also been removed for **any resources for the region** your EIP is located in." [emphasis mine]

Comment: Ran into same issue and the time of your question coincides with the start of my issue. May I ask what region your instance is located in? Requested a restriction removal as well.

Comment: @beks6 — eu-central-1

Comment: Thanks, got solved my problem the same way. Annoying that there is no notification from AWS. Lost days in troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

From [Remove the Port 25 Restriction From Your EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/):

> Amazon EC2 restricts traffic on port 25 of all EC2 instances by default, but you can request for this restriction to be removed.

It says that you must:

- Create a DNS A record
- Request AWS to remove the port 25 restriction on your instance via a *Request to Remove Email Sending Limitations* form

Alternatively, you could consider using **Amazon Simple Email Service** (Amazon SES) to send email, rather than sending it directly from the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something is blocking the traffic on port 25. Please check the following things.

- Check if there are any rules set in VPC ACL to block traffic.
- Check if there are any recent updates to iptables on OS.
- check for any recent changes to DNS / Route 53.

Comment: VPC ACLs were mentioned in the question. iptables it a good suggestion, I forgot to mention that I'd already done the — and there are non affecting port 25. I don't understand the DNS/Route 53 suggestion. What would I be looking for, there?